# How do system services work in snaps

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap

When creating a snap, and according to the [syntax of the snapcraft.yaml file](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/build-apps/snapcraft-syntax), the `daemon` keyword can be added to specify that the app will be run as a system service. As an example of such declaration:

```
apps:
  tinyproxy:
    command: ./launcher.sh
    daemon: simple
    plugs: [network,network-bind]
```

However, what does it exactly mean to be a system service in a snap? That is, what's their lifecycle (start, restart, stop...)? Can I monitor them running in the system with the usual tools (`ps`, `top`, etc)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/build-apps/debug/

### Testing a service

To test a service it must be installed first. Once it is installed, systemd's `systemctl` command can be used to see if the service starts and runs as expected, for example:

```
systemctl status snap.<name>.<appname>
```

#### Finding the logs

The `journalctl` command can be used to inspect the messages that the service sends to `stdout`/`stderr`, for example:

```
journalctl -u snap.<name>.<appname>
```

Services may log additional data to syslog (`/var/log/syslog`) or to custom log directories. Note that custom log directories must be in a path that the service can write to (usually `SNAP_DATA`).

#### Getting a core dump

To enable core dumps you have to configure a place to write them to through sysfs. For instance you can use

```
$ echo "/tmp/core.%e.%p" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

to ensure that your coredumps get written into the `/tmp` directory regardless of where `CWD` of the process that received a signal was.

Comment: Thanks! Also, I got a tip that an easy way to debug issues with a service not starting is to temporarily uncomment the `daemon: simple` line to make it behave as a regular app, and then manually start the "appified" service as `sudo /snap/bin/<servicename>`

Comment: is it possible to redirect the logs to a custom file instead of journal?