# nextcloud server with snap package on xenial

Tags: 16.04, snap, nextcloud

I want to install nextcloud under xenial, and as fashion is to snap I test,
I do not find much info about snap packets apart from how to install them.

I understood that it was a chroot environment in readonly (basically touch nothing, not to break)

Questions:

- where are the logs?
- How to restart the httpd service included in the snap?
- How change an apache parameter ?

Thank you for your help !

Vincent

Comment: Since snaps include their dependencies, how to change the port depends on the snap in question. [This](https://github.com/nextcloud/nextcloud-snap/issues/134) might prove relevant for the Nextcloud snap.

Answer (score 3):

found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/784489/how-do-system-services-work-in-snaps/) the answer for where are the logs

the short answer is in  **/var/snap/** nextcloud/current/apache/logs for apache logs .

and how restart / check the status :

short answer :

```
systemctl status snap.nextcloud.apache
```

Still looking for : How change an apache parameters (eg port listenning)