# Does Snappy explicitly include webapps as a use-case?

Tags: server, snap, webapps, web-development

I was surprised to read [War on Snaps](http://mhall119.com/2017/03/war-on-snaps/), an example of a webapp being packaged using Snappy (in this case using Apache Tomcat and a Java WAR file). I also found [a question about Snappy/NodeJS web applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/744696/how-to-create-snappy-nodejs-web-application). I thought that Snappy was only for desktop apps.

Are these examples of non-crucial frameworks, or does Snappy explicitly support web-server use cases? I'm looking for official documentation that confirms that packaging and delivering web applications to internet-readable servers are considered part of the Snappy vision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snaps are definitely not just for desktop applications. Snaps work great for that use-case, but they make even more sense when you start considering IoT-type devices, where they need to be kept secure and remotely upgradeable. This is why [Ubuntu Core](https://www.ubuntu.com/core) was created, which is based entirely upon snaps (including the kernel and OS).

Consider the [Nextcloud Box](https://nextcloud.com/box/), which is based on Ubuntu Core, where Nextcloud (a web application) is packaged as a snap. Not only are web applications a valid use-case for snaps, they are a perfect one.